# Jquery removing objects from array for images preview using html5

Tags: jquery, html

I succesfully got the preview images to get removed from the viewing area but it doesn't actually remove it from the array. I cannot figure out how to remove it like it was never selected, please help me out!

**http://jsfiddle.net/ERZVC/**

```
 var count=0;
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var $fileUpload = $("input#files[type='file']");
    count=count+parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);

    if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length) > 6 || count>5) {
        alert("You can only upload a maximum of 5 files");
        count=count-parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    var files = evt.target.files;
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) {
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/><span class="remove_img_preview"></span>'].join('');
                document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
            };
        })(f);

        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}

$('#files').change(function(evt){
    handleFileSelect(evt);
});  

$('#list').on('click', '.remove_img_preview',function () {
    $(this).parent('span').remove();
});
```

html

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="image_file_arr[]" multiple>
<br><output id="list"></output>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clear an image preview file that was removed from the array with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470379/clear-an-image-preview-file-that-was-removed-from-the-array-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ERZVC/1/).

The only mistake is you have not decreased counter on removing file.

Thanks.

```
 var count=0;
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var $fileUpload = $("input#files[type='file']");
    count=count+parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);

    if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length) > 6 || count>5) {
        alert("You can only upload a maximum of 5 files");
        count=count-parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    var files = evt.target.files;
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) {
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/><span class="remove_img_preview"></span>'].join('');
                document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
            };
        })(f);

        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}

$('#files').change(function(evt){
    handleFileSelect(evt);
});  

$('#list').on('click', '.remove_img_preview',function () {
    $(this).parent('span').remove();
    count--;
});
```

Comment: nice! this works for the preivew, now what if I upload 4 images then remove 2, on submit, will it only upload the 2 images in the preview?

Comment: For that you have to remove that file from files array on remove button click using splice method of javascript. Here is reference link: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp . Also you can view your files array using alert(JSON.stringify(files)). put this line after var files = evt.target.files; in your code and you can see list of files uploaded. Thanks

Comment: Can you please show me how to put these two in the code so that after it sees the files, it removes the ones that were click to be removed?

Comment: can you please help me out with this? I am not sure how to add these codes in